# Difference between 与，和 and 跟?

Tags: word-choice

Do the following three sentences mean the same thing, that is, can they be used interchangeably?

1. 她的父母就来我们家与我的家人见面了。
2. 她的父母就来我们家和我的家人见面了。
3. 她的父母就来我们家跟我的家人见面了。

Comment: http://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/378/25 Related?

Answer (score 20):

I would reword the three sentences as follows instead:

1. 她父母来我家**与**我家人见面。
2. 她父母来我家**和**我家人见面。
3. 她父母来我家**跟**我家人见面。

In this case, they can be used interchangeably as each one of them means "and".
Here are the minute differences:

- **与 [yǔ]** is more elegant and formal, and is usually applied to similar items of abstract and contrasting nature. E.g. 天与地 (heaven and earth), 是与非 (yes and no).
- **和 [hé]** is more general and informal, and can be applied to list dissimilar items and more often on objects. E.g. 汽车和现金 (car and cash), 蓝宝石和翡翠 (sapphire and jade).
- **跟 [gēn]** is used more often in speech, and is usually applied to similar items and more often on humans. E.g. 他跟她 (he and she), 我跟你 (you and I).

Answer (score 15):

跟 is totally oral and informal. The other two can be used in both formal and informal situations although in oral conversation 和 is more common. A person who speaks 与 (together with other formal/"classical" words) too much may be considered fastidious and/or pedantic.

They have the exact same meaning. Other than formality, people picks the one that is easy to pronounce and sounds smooth. For example, 英语与法语 is hard to pronounce so people may prefer 英语和法语; on the other hand 战争与和平 sounds better than 战争和和平.

When connecting words with "classical feeling", such as one-character words, 与 is used even in oral language, e.g. 学与玩. In this case 学和玩 sounds okay but 学跟玩 sounds somehow unnatural.

But again they mean the same and are interchangeable. It's only about tone, feeling and idioms.

Answer (score 3):

与 is usually used more formal.
和 is between 与 and 跟, plus it is used more often than others.
跟 is usually used more oral.

Comment: Welcome to the site. An upvote to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

与，和，跟, you can replace one of these with any of the others. But there are some slight differences in usage.

跟 is informal, only used in speaking.

与 and 和 are exchangeable on most occasions. 和 is the most commonly used, while 与 is a bit more formal, and it is more used similarly to "with" in English. For instance, "A is associated with B and C" is translated as "A与B和C有关" in preference to "A和B与C有关". The former is much more natural because 和 emphasises Juxtaposition while 与 stresses correlation. Sure you can say(not write!) "A和B和C有关", but you have to place stress on "B" in order to avoid ambiguity.

P.S.以及 is the most formal one, which means "additionally", usually used in writing rather than in daily conversation. You can seldom hear 以及 from a native Chinese speaker unless in a speech, report or else.