# What are the different words for "and" that can be used in a list and how do they differ?

Tags: word-choice, characters

In a sentence with a list like:

我喜歡飯、電視**和**電影。

**What are the different words for "and" that can be used, and how to they differ in usage?**

---

I've seen at least 及 and 和 being used.

Comment: have a look of this thread, it listed most words of "and": http://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/17953/也-和-并-与-及-跟-而-同-difference

Comment: put 等 at the end along with a word denoting the category to which the enumerated items belong, s. e.g. jukuu: 
 
  
     
 
1.   
 但较常用的皮革原料来自牛(包括小牛和公牛)、绵羊和羔羊、山羊和小山羊、马、骡、斑马、水牛、猪、海豹、海象、鲸和鳄鱼等动物。
 

4.   
 其五，对走私、贩卖、运输、制造毒品等严重的毒品罪犯处以死刑。

 99.   
 试比较thin、 skinny、underweight、 slim等词的用法.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

used to connect words: 和; 與; 跟; 及; 以及;

和 can be used everywhere.
跟 is used in oral cases mostly.
與, 及, 以及 are used mostly in writing.

used to connect clauses or sentences: 並且; 而且