# How to translate "and" to Chinese

Tags: translation, grammar, meaning, usage

I would like some clarification on translating 'and' into Chinese. I know 和 and 跟 can be used as 'and' with nouns, 也 can be used with verbs, and often 'and' isn't translated but a comma is used. But recently I encountered 与 as 'and' where I thought 和 would be used. My question is, are there other words that are  typically translated as 'and' in Chinese, and in what situations do you use these characters as 'and' (I still don't have a great understanding of 也 or 跟 as 'and'), and when do you not need to translate 'and' at all. In other words, I am looking for a summary of 'and' in Chinese.

Comment: searching site with 和 跟 与 yields relevant results, esp. https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/17953/%e4%b9%9f-%e5%92%8c-%e5%b9%b6-%e4%b8%8e-%e5%8f%8a-%e8%b7%9f-%e8%80%8c-%e5%90%8c-difference

Answer (score 3):

My summary of 'and' in Chinese:

> "財富 (和) 聲望" = "wealth (and) prestige"

'和' denotes 'wealth' and 'prestige' are at the same level in term of emphasis (implies they come in together as a unit)

> "財富 (與) 聲望" = "wealth (and) prestige" / "wealth (and also) prestige"

'與' emphasize the first item 'wealth' slightly more than the second item 'prestige' (imply prestige comes after wealth)

> "財富 (及) 聲望" = "wealth (and) prestige"/ "wealth (and) prestige (in addition)"

'及' emphasizes the first item 'wealth' more heavily over the second item 'prestige' (implies prestige is an addition to 'wealth'

*Notice the compound word '與及' (also/ in addition of)*

~

> "你 (和) 我" = "you (and) I"

'和' indicates 'you' and 'I' are at the same level of emphasis

> "你 (與) 我" = "you (and) I" / you (and) me (also)"

'與' emphasizes the first item 'you' slightly more than the second item 'I' (implies thing effect you slight more than me)

> "你 (跟) 我" = "you (and) I" / "you (with) I "

'跟'  emphasizes the second item 'I' more than the first item 'you' (implies 'you' following 'I'. e.g. "你跟我一起工作" = "you work with me together")

> You can omit '和' just like you can omit 'and' in English sometimes

"財富聲望" = 'wealth, prestige' (*as a single unit*)

"你我" = "you and I" = "we" (*it is a classical style of speech*)

> *也 means 'also' or 'too', as in "我**也**是中國人" (I am Chinese **too**/ I am **also** Chinese),  "我也去 (I would **also** go/ I would go **too** )*

*In Cantonese '同' is equal to '和'*

Comment: How would you say 'and' with a verb or an adjective, like "I like to run and jump" or "She is tall and blonde"?

Comment: 我喜欢跑步和跳高。 她又高又是金发碧眼的or（她是很高而且又是金发碧眼的）很高 means tall， 金发碧眼的 means blond。 而且 means and。So 而且 is another way to say and。

Comment: @mathnoob 我喜欢跑步和跳高 is OK. But your second sentence is quite unnatural. I recommend 她金发碧眼，个子很高。又……又……is often used to combine words of the same syllables or structure, E.G. 又高又壮，又吵又闹，又是唱歌又是跳舞…… By the way, 金发 is blond, 碧眼 is blue-eyed.

Comment: see grammar on conjunctios