# Does 跟 and 和 sounds the same meaning in this case?

Tags: meaning

Does `跟` and `和` sounds the same meaning in this case ?

> 我今天跟妈妈去买菜
>
> 我今天和妈妈去买菜

Comment: 和 [neutral]
跟 [northern colloquial]  search site for previous discussion, e.g. https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/17953/%e4%b9%9f-%e5%92%8c-%e5%b9%b6-%e4%b8%8e-%e5%8f%8a-%e8%b7%9f-%e8%80%8c-%e5%90%8c-difference esp. 2nd answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both '跟' and '和' contain the meaning of 'and/ with'

> Therefore, both "我今天跟妈妈去买菜" and "我今天和妈妈去买菜" can be interpreted as "My mother **and** I go to buy food ingredients today"

But '跟' also contains the meaning of "follow"

> Therefore, "我今天跟妈妈去买菜" can be interpreted as "I follow my mother to go to buy food ingredients today"
>
> the problem is writing '我今天' makes  '我' the subject, and '跟妈妈去买菜' the verb phrase; instead of '我跟妈妈' being the subject and '去买菜' being the verb

If you want to avoid the confusion, you should write "我跟妈妈今天去买菜" or "我和妈妈今天去买菜"(I and my mother go to buy food ingredients today)

- '我跟妈妈' (I and my mother) -  would clearly be the subject
- in '我今天跟妈妈去买菜',  '我' would be the subject, and  '跟妈妈去买菜' could mean 'follow my mother...' or 'with my mother...'
- if you wrote '我今天和妈妈去买菜', even the subject is still '我' but '今天和妈妈去买菜' can only mean "go to buy food ingredients **with** my mother today"